# Prove or Disprove: Finitely generated Artinian module is Noetherian.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

> Prove or Disprove: Finitely generated Artinian module is Noetherian.

I think it is true and I am trying to prove it. I am considering reducing the case to Artinian rings. Say $M$ is finitely generated Artinian $R$-module. Then $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is an Artinian $R$-module. Thus $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is Artinian as an $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$-module. That is, $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is an Artinian ring. We know that by Hopkins, $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is a Noetherian ring. Thus $M$ when seen as an $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$-module is Noetherian. I wonder how I can prove that $M$ is Noetherian as an $R$-module?

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61695/are-there-any-finitely-generated-artinian-modules-that-are-not-noetherian) for perhaps a partial answer. Not clear that the full answer is known.

Comment: In short: induct on the number of generators, and for cyclic modules use a simpler version of the argument given here.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *trivially* yes: If $M$ is finitely generated and artinian, then $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$ is an artinian ring, hence noetherian. Now just notice that the $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$-submodules of $M$ coincide with the $R$-submodules of $M$.

Comment: Is that for the reason why we can treat any $R$-module M as an $R/Ann(M)$-module by defining $\bar{r}m=rm$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any module element $m \in M$, there is an injection of $R$ modules $R/\operatorname{Ann}(m) \hookrightarrow M: r \mapsto r \cdot m$. If $M$ is finitely generated, I have the map
$$R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) \oplus \dotsb \oplus R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_n) \twoheadrightarrow M$$
which is the sum of the inclusions. If $M$ is Artinian, then each $R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$ is Artinian because it's a submodule. The structure of $R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$ as an $R$ module is the same as its structure as an $R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$ module, so we can say that $R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$ is an Artinian ring, so a Noetherian ring, so a Noetherian $R$ module.

Now $M$ receives a surjection from a Noetherian module, so it is Noetherian.

I'm not really sure why you'd use $R/\operatorname{Ann}(M)$ here. Perhaps someone could enlighten me.

Comment: Maybe since $\mathrm{Ann}(M)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Ann}(m_i)$, and $R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)\hookrightarrow R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_1) \oplus \dotsb \oplus R/\operatorname{Ann}(m_n)$?

Comment: @user26857 Yes, but why is that necessary to the proof? And why is it easy to see that $R/\operatorname{Ann}(M)$ is Artinian, unless you set up the above map?

Comment: Who said it's necessary? It's convenient since the module structures are the same and then $M$ can be supposed faithful.

Comment: Assume $M$ is faithful. @user26857 left the proof of the fact that $R$ is artinian to the reader. The proof that came to my mind was to observe that $R$ embeds in $M^n$ for $n$ large enough. I don't know if it's the proof user26857 had in mind, or if there are simpler arguments...

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Why does $R$ embed in $M^n$?

Comment: @EricAuld - Map $r$ to $(rg_1,\dots,rg_n)$ where $g_1,\dots,g_n$ are generators.